# conda install -c anaconda protobuf

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I am getting the above error when i am trying to run train.py in tensor flow object detection API . 
Can someone help me ?
I am trying out this code 
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't compiled your protofbuf libraries then you need to execute the command specified in the following link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation
I did notice an issue with the latest protobuf compiler available. I successfully compiled using version 3.4.0 of protoc available here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.4.0